# Is there a way to use a windowing function to keep a minimum total of 0 instead of having to have a loop?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, window-functions

I'm trying to avoid using a loop to have a running total. This is a simplified version; the real version includes subtotals by a couple of categories. I know I can do this using a windowing function [@Xata2], but I can't think of a non-loop way to do it if you restrict the total to non-negative (i.e., if the total is negative, use 0 instead) [@Xata3], because any conditions I put are on the current line, not the cumulative total.

```
    DECLARE   @Xata TABLE (
          ID            INTEGER IDENTITY
        , result        INTEGER
        )

    DECLARE   @Xata2 TABLE (
          ID            INTEGER IDENTITY
        , result        INTEGER
        , total         INTEGER
        )

    DECLARE   @Xata3 TABLE (
          ID            INTEGER IDENTITY
        , result        INTEGER
        , total         INTEGER
        )

    DECLARE   @result   INTEGER
            , @total    INTEGER
            , @Counter  INTEGER

    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
    INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)

    -- @Xata2: WINDOWING FUNCTION

    INSERT INTO @Xata2
        SELECT    result
                , SUM(result) OVER (ORDER BY ID)
            FROM @Xata

    SELECT    ID
            , result
            , total AS total_x2_neg
        FROM @Xata2

    SET @Counter = 0

    WHILE @Counter < (SELECT MAX(ID) FROM @Xata)
        BEGIN
            SET @Counter += 1

            SELECT @result = result FROM @Xata WHERE ID = @Counter
            SET @total = ISNULL((SELECT total FROM @Xata3 WHERE ID = @Counter - 1), 0)

            INSERT INTO @Xata3
                SELECT    @result
                        , IIF(@result + @total < 0, 0, @result + @total)

        END

    SELECT    ID
            , result
            , total AS total_x3_noneg
        FROM @Xata3
```

[image]

Comment: Can you explain what is the logic behind your query and what it is supposed to be doing?

Comment: This is the best repro I have seen in a long time. Upvote

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I appreciate the repro too, but I'd prefer fix values to have a fix exepcted output. Using random values here makes it more difficult to see, if the solution returns correctly... Anyway, +1 from my side.

Comment: @DaveX Let's assume row 7 contains a result `-6`. Should `total_x3_noneg` result in `0` or `5`?

Comment: @Menno, I think your question is answered with row 7 to 8. We have a 1 and a result of `-3` and there we see a `0`. I take this as: Compute the subtraction, but never below zero.

Comment: @Shnugo You're absolutely right!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first attempt was not returning correctly, thank you @Menno for the hint.

Try this approach with a *recursive CTE*

```
DECLARE   @Xata TABLE (ID INTEGER IDENTITY
                      ,result INTEGER);

INSERT INTO @Xata (result) VALUES(-3),(1),(2),(2),(0),(0),(-4),(-3),(2),(3);

WITH recCte AS
(
    SELECT ID
          ,result
          ,CASE WHEN result>0 THEN result ELSE 0 END AS runningTotalNoNeg 
    FROM @Xata 
    WHERE ID=1

    UNION ALL

    SELECT d.ID
          ,d.result
          ,CASE WHEN r.runningTotalNoNeg + d.result > 0 then r.runningTotalNoNeg + d.result ELSE 0 END
    FROM @Xata d
    INNER JOIN recCte r ON d.ID=r.ID+1
)
SELECT *
FROM recCte;
```

the result

```
ID  rt  runningTotalNoNeg
1  -3   0
2   1   1
3   2   3
4   2   5
5   0   5
6   0   5
7  -4   1
8  -3   0
9   2   2
10  3   5
```

Comment: The complexity is with the given data in for example row 7. The logic @DaveX is after is that the running total may not drop below 0.

Comment: +1 I didn't see a working approach with a window-function either, the recursive CTE might be the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 0):

***EDIT***

I wrapped the whole thing in another running total.

When

EXCELLENT repro by the way - I wish everyone worked like this

```
 DECLARE   @Xata TABLE (
      ID            INTEGER IDENTITY
    , result        INTEGER
    )



INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)
INSERT INTO @Xata (result) SELECT ROUND(RAND()* 9 - 4.5, 0)


SELECT x.ID, x.result, x.RT1, SUM(IIF(x.RT1<0,0,x.RT1)) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as RT2
from (
        SELECT  ID,  result
            , SUM(result) OVER (ORDER BY ID) as RT1
        FROM @Xata
    ) as x
ORDER BY x.ID
```

Comment: This won't result in value `1` for row 2, will it?

Comment: The sample data is randomised so row 2 is always different. But for an input value of `1` (in field `r1`), yes it returns `1`. Why don't you run the code yourself?

Comment: hmmm hang on a sec - you're now that I recheck, you're right, it doesn't return what the OP is after

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid No, your edited version does not return as expected. You can try the *mockup* from my answer to use the same values as used in the question...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `sum` window function with `case` statement:

```
select id, result,
       case when [sum] < 0 then 0 else [sum]
from (
    select id,
           result,
           sum(result) over (order by id) [sum]
    from MyTable
) a
```

Comment: That was exactly my approach before I had to change it. The OP wants to use negative values but not below zero. So it is not enough just to sum up the positive values... In the given example the `-4` is used to step from `5` to `1`. If the `5` was 4 or less it should step down to `0`...

Comment: Sorry, but your edit does not repair this. You can try this with the *mockup* of my answer... It is not enough just to surpress negative sum values...